# how do I print newline in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I am learning sqlite3.
I wanna insert a separator between two tables, how do I do this?

```
-- show Table [exam]                                                                                
SELECT * from exam;   

-- here I wanna print a newline as separator
-- how to do this?

-- show Table [examlog]                                                                             
SELECT * from examlog;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
select '';
```

on a line by itself.

Answer (score 5):

If it's still of any use:

```
.print ''
```

will print a new line in the output.

Answer (score 0):

In [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3) 3.7.16 there are some new [core functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html). With char() any characters could be written:

`char(X1,X2,...,XN) The char(X1,X2,...,XN) function returns a string composed of characters having the unicode code point values of integers X1 through XN, respectively.`